# EntityManager.find() or EntityManager.CreateQuery() is inconsistent while fetching data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

In my `hibernate 5.0`, I am using `EntityManager.find(class,id)` and It is fetching object based on Id, but it is inconsistent, some time it is not fetching data and data is available in `DB (MySql)`, I tried with `EntityMa,nager.CreateQuery("")` also but same issue, as I debugged and found it's not hitting database, I am unable to figure out the root cause. Below is my `DAO and model`

```
 @Override
public User getUserById(int userId)
{
    User user = null;
    try {
        logger.info("fetching user details of userid :"+userId);
        user = entityManager.find(User.class,userId);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.error("Error finding user : " + e);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Model:

```
        @Entity @Table(name = "user", 
          uniqueConstraints=  @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"email_id"})) 
         @JsonIgnoreProperties({  "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" }) 
           @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
          @XmlRootElement(name = "user") 
         public class User implements Serializable {

        @Id     
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")     
        @Column(name = "user_id")   
        private int userId; 

        /** some more column and getter setter **/  

        //Mappings

        @JsonIgnore     
        @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)    
        private  Set<Contract_Reviewer> contract_Reviewer;      

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")     
        private Department departments;
 }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that the entity with the queried `id` is persisted before you query the database? Have you tried to use a test database with static initialized test data? A remark on your code: from the looks of it, it seems you pass your business object through to the endpoint and thus expose it to the client. You should re-map the POJO into a `DTO` to not expose your business objects to clients.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Turing85, I took the dumb and tested in my local, the id exist. Thanks Dave for edit

Comment: it's return null for all User attributes but when I will try to call user.getxxx(), it's returning the data, strange, don't know how it's working